# Units of Work and Backout in DataPower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I Have set the configuration as below

```
Units of Work : 1
Automatic Backout: on.
Backout Threshold: 3
Backout Queue Name: Queue Name is given.
```

So according to this settings , since threshold value is 3 and in case of failure, there should be 4 transaction in the probe?

can you please confirm

Thanks 
Vathsa

Comment: Can any one update Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only one as it is the same transaction in DP but three transport retires.